# Expresiones regulares (regex) - Hacer una coincidencia que agrupe los números enteros y sus respectivas elevaciones - Java

Tags: java, regex

Tengo este string de ejemplo: `5-9^6^-2^9-4`
Y quiero que el resultado sea: `9^6^-2^9`
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este regex podría valer

`[0-9]+(\^[+-]?[0-9]+)+/g`

Explicado por partes:

1. `[0-9]+`: un número del 0 al 9 con mínimo una cifra
2. `\^`: el símbolo ^, con el carácter de escape ya que es un carácter especial
3. `[+-]?`: opcionalmente, a continuación, puede ir un símbolo + o un símbolo -
4. `[0-9]+`:  un número del 0 al 9 con mínimo una cifra

Repitiéndose los tres ultimos patrones mínimo una vez, por ello se encuentra entre parentesís con un + al final `(\^[+-]?[0-9]+)+`

Te aconsejo usar la página [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Un saludo!